# Git with ldap authorization

Tags: git, authentication, ldap

Is there a way to authorize user via ldap on a git repository? Or phrased slightly differently: Is there a way to deny people pull/push if they are not in a specific ldap group?

Edit:
Yes, great idea using PAM and/or a hook. Does anyone have experience using git in combination with pam_ldap?

Answer (score 8):

Should work:

- Access git repos over SSH using standard logins (nothing unusual here).
- Make your git repos have access permissions for a certain group, which particular logins have membership of.
- Use pam-ldap to make your standard login system work with LDAP.

If there's a more specific way, that JUST checks ldap without affecting the rest of your system?  I don't know, but it's probably possible with a pre-commit hook, or something like that.

Comment: a pre-commit hook is run client side

Answer (score 3):

You can use `update` or `pre-receive` [hook](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks) to do **additional** access control; see [update-paranoid](http://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git;a=blob;f=contrib/hooks/update-paranoid;hb=master) (in Perl) from `contrib/hooks/` for an example (it doesn't uses LDAP, but you can always modify it to use it, using for example DBI via [DBD::LDAP](http://p3rl.org/DBD::LDAP) to store permission configuration, or [Authen::Simple::LDAP](http://p3rl.org/Authen::Simple::LDAP) directly).

It might be possible to enhance tools such like [gitosis](http://eagain.net/gitweb/?p=gitosis.git) (in Python) or [gitolite](http://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite), which are used to access git repositories via SSH without requiring to set up (perhaps limited) separate shell account for each user, to use LDAP for authentication.

Answer (score 2):

The straightforward solution I've experienced is the following:

1. Setup [CentrifyDC Express](http://www.centrify.com/express/free-active-directory-tools-for-linux-mac.asp) to provide you pam-ldap;
2. Access your [GIT repositories via SSH](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols#The-SSH-Protocol).

*Et voilà!*

Comment: Or **additionally**, you could setup [PAM-based HTTP/S](http://icephoenix.us/linuxunix/apache-and-http-authentication-with-pam/) access to your [GIT repos](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols#The-HTTP/S-Protocol).

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into Gitorious with Craig Andrews LDAP plugin.

Gitorious is a well respected (open source) solution for corporate environments providing web and SSH access to repositories.

Craig's additions to the code base make LDAP a source for authorization and authentication.

https://gitorious.org

https://gitorious.org/gitorious/mainline/merge_requests/138 <-- merge in LDAP support

Hopefully the code will be merged into the mainline of Gitorious soon so we wont have to patch it ourselves.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to use git over [smart-http](http://progit.org/2010/03/04/smart-http.html). If you use this protocol you can set up your [Apache server to authenticate through LDAP](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_auth_ldap.html), and then have your git transferring data over http.